# Couldn't submit the form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I want to create a new object based on certain parameters.

In my new.html.haml

```
%table
   %thead
      %tr
        %td
          = f.label: type
         %td
           = select_tag :question_type, options_for_select
    %tbody#content
```

javascript:

```
$('#question_type').change(function(){
     $.ajax({
        data: { question_type: $(this).val() },
        url: window.location.href,
        dataType: 'script'
     });
  });
```

In my new.js.haml

```
$('#content').html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "question_form"))}");
```

in `_question_form.html.haml`

```
= form_for @question, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
  %tr
    %td{:style => 'text-align:right;'}
      = f.label :name
    %td
      = f.text_field :name
  %tr
    %td
    %td
      = f.button :Submit, :value => 'Create'
```

In my controller

```
def new
   @question = Question.new

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
   end
  end

  def create
   @question.save

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html (redirect_to questions_path)
     format.js
   end
  end
```

All are working fine, But I can't able to submit the form after entering question name. How to get this form to submit?

Comment: what do you mean by "can't able to"? can't click the button? or submitting the form doesn't go to the create action? or something else?

Comment: Pls help me. I am struggling with this for last 2 days.

Comment: @jvnill yes, I can able to click the button but I couldn't able to submit the form.When the form is submit only I can able to call the create method, but I can't able to submit form.

Comment: What does Firebug console show when you click the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies in your html structure.  you should put the form outside the table.

```
= form_for @question do |f|
  %table
```

be reminded that this will submit the question type which you can just ignore in your create action

UPDATE:

```
# new.html.haml
#form-content= render 'question_form'

# _question_form.html.haml
= form_for @question, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
  %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %td= f.label: type
        %td= select_tag :question_type, options_for_select
    %tbody
      - if params[:question_type].present?
        %tr
          %td{:style => 'text-align:right;'}= f.label :name
          %td= f.text_field :name
        %tr
          %td
          %td= f.button :Submit, :value => 'Create'

# new.js.haml
$('#form-content').html("#{escape_javascript render("question_form")}");
```

Comment: your answer is correct.I tried that too, but I couldn't pass ther form instance to my _question_form.html.haml, this page has many inputs based on the question_type. Atleast help me to pass the form instance to _question.html.haml

Comment: try my updated answer.  what you want to do is put the form in the partial.